# How to enable CRUD operations from multiple locations and synchronized the results?

Tags: database

Say we have several campuses each of which is able to do CRUD operation on the student data. The database used is MySQL and the database schema is the same in every place.

What is the best solution to allow each campus to do CRUD operations on the data and have any change to the data in one campus being synchronized / reflected in the other campuses?

Answer (score 0):

If all the campuses have internet access or are networked, develop a web based application.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious answer to this is to use a single instance of mysql used by any of those campuses.

If you asked this because of scaling reasons. You might consider something like the use of [mysql_proxy](https://launchpad.net/mysql-proxy) to distribute reads accross campus distinct read nodes which replicate from a single master node. Every campus might write to this single node and the read nodes replicate from that master node.

Another alternative is the use of mysqls cluster capabilities. See e.g. here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/ndbcluster.html.

If you do not have any geographical problems with your campuses you might also put a single multi tenant application in place like e.g. a web-application.

Every approach requires something like a Campus internal VPN or something like that.